# Datapipeline and Mule

Tags: mule, aws-sdk, amazon-data-pipeline

Which version of MULE will be compatible for AWSSDK for Datapipeline, We need to activate Datapipeline through Enterprises version of Mule. Since its Cloud, we can use any mule version from 3.6. Please help us. Right now the Jar version are causing issues, such as NoSuchmethod error or Field not found.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the latest version of AWS SDK.